# Adding to a Many to Many relationship given primary keys

Tags: django, django-models

Given primary keys to two different objects with a many to many relationship, what is the most effective way to add the relationship that results in the least amount of database hits?

I'm thinking something like the below, but it results in hitting the database twice.

```
ob = A.objects.get(pk=pk_a)
ob.B.add(pk_b)
```

Is it possible to only hit the database once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to only hit the database once?

**Yes**. You can just create a model object of the `through` model, like:

```
A.b.through.objects.create(a_id=pk_a, b_id=pk_b)
```

Given the model is `A`, and `b` is the name of the `ManyToManyField`.